# Undefined control sequence when it is defined?

Tags: amsmath

I have defined a command - `\renewcommand{\U}{\mbox{$\cal U$}}`. But when I compile, it says:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<\recently read/> \cal 
l.489 If $\U
            $ is an open ultrafilter on $X$ then $\Us$ is used to denote
```

If I change `\renewcommand` to `\newcommand`, it says `\U is already defined`

- List item

.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that `\cal` has been declared obsolete in LaTeX more than *twenty* years ago. Do `\newcommand{\U}{\mathcal{U}}`. I don't know why `\U` should be already defined, it isn't in the default set up. Please, make a minimal example of code showing the issue.

Comment: @egreg: Actually I didn't define **\U** before. But If I write "\newcommand{\U} .....", it says it is defined. So it forced me to change it to "\renewcommand{\U} .....".  So how can I list that?

Answer (score 2):

Note that (as the error help text says) the undefined command is the last command before the end of the first line of the error message, not the command mentioned on the last line of the error message (which is the line in the source file where the error occurred).

So in this case `\cal` is undefined (not `\U`).

`\cal` is a plain TeX command the nearest equivalent LaTeX command is `\mathcal`. `\cal` is not defined by the format, although for compatibility with older versions of LaTeX (prior to 1993) some document classes (including the standard `article` class) may define it.

You almost certainly would be better to not have the box and nested math mode so

```
\newcommand\U{\mathcal{U}}
```

or (if you have already defined `\U`) the same, with `\renewcommand`

Comment: I find `\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}` in `article.cls`. ;-)

Comment: @egreg oh I wonder who did that:-) will fix

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thank you, Sir. I changed \cal into \mathcal, it is working fine.
But I wonder, how other commands with \cal working correctly.

Comment: @Achu impossible to say as you have only posted fragments. Any package or class you have used my or may not define `\cal` but you have given no information.